# Need help to find a solution for excel spreadsheet 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Example:

```
Column A        Column B      Column C     Column D      Column E
Maricar         Gener         Adriel                     3 (It's like an auto sum)
Jocelyn         Gener                      Jericho       3
Jocelyn         Maricar                                  2
Ingkay          Gener         Jho                        3
```

Comment: I have no idea what solvent spreadsheets dissolve in.  Do you have a question that relates to the table you posted?

Comment: whats up with this spreadsheet ?

Comment: @fixer1234: If you aren't part of the solution, then you're part of the precipitate.  :-)  ⁠

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you need to count how many fields have text on the row and put that on Column E.

In that case the formula on `E2` must be:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:D2,"<>"&"")
```

Comment: This answer actually reduces to `=COUNTIF(A2:D2, "<>")`, which works, although (IMO) it looks cryptic.   `=COUNTA(A2:D2)` is even simpler.

Comment: @Scott Great Scott!!!